# Openpyxl only reads one number

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I'm creating a script where I am pulling out numbers from columns A, B, and C 1200 times. Column A is just numbers - 1, 2, 3, and so on. Once I get to 10, I run into the issue where it will try to run the "1" and then the "0". I'm pretty new to coding, and it definitely isn't the cleanest script. This is my code -

```
wb = load_workbook(filename = 'SG_Huron.xlsx', data_only=True )
worksheet = wb['SG_Huron']
cells = worksheet['A2:C1202']
#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
#Change: AOI # and respective Great Lake Basin [Erie, Huron, Michigan, Ontario, StClair, Superior]
for i1, i2, i3 in cells:
    aoi_list = '%s' %(i1.value)
    usaf= '%s' %(i2.value)
    wban= '%s' %(i3.value)
    Great_Lake_Basin = 'Huron'
    print(aoi, usaf, wban)

    for aoi in aoi_list:
        #Path for final output 
        path_trunk = "C:/job/projects/Hydro/%s/%s/Inputs" %(Great_Lake_Basin, aoi)
        #Path for AOI Data
        path_aoi = "C:/job/a_prep_DEM_NLCD/%s/%s.shp" %(Great_Lake_Basin, aoi)
        #aoi data file name
        file_aoi = "%s.shp" %(aoi)
        #Path for DEM Data
        path_dem = "C:/job/a_prep_DEM_NLCD/DEM/"
        #Change: FIle name for raw DEM data
        file_dem = "elev_cm_%s.tif" %(Great_Lake_Basin)
```

Which then gives me (first the print function)

```
10 720321 4893
1:C:/iTree/projects/Hydro/Huron/1/Inputs exists
2:C:/iTree/a_prep_DEM_NLCD/DEM//Huron/ exists.
5: C:/iTree/a_prep_DEM_NLCD/DEM//Huron/Huron_1_dem.txt exists.
Creating final C:/iTree/projects/Hydro/Huron/1/Inputs/dem.dat
6. Creating final C:/iTree/projects/Hydro/Huron/1/Inputs/Evaporation.dat
6. Creating final C:/iTree/projects/Hydro/Huron/1/Inputs/Weather.dat
6. Creating final C:/iTree/projects/Hydro/Huron/1/Inputs/SolarRadiation.dat
1:C:/iTree/projects/Hydro/Huron/0/Inputs exists
2:C:/iTree/a_prep_DEM_NLCD/DEM//Huron/ exists.
3: Creating C:/iTree/a_prep_DEM_NLCD/DEM//Huron/Huron_0_elev_cm_raw.tif
```

Comment: In the 1st 'for' statement you assign aoi_list to the string value of the first column value i.e. numbers 1, 2, 3 etc. The next for loop **for aoi in aoi_list** will provide the each character of that string on each iteration so for the value '1', the 1st loop provides '1' and loop ends; for value '10', the 1st loop provides '1' and 2nd loop provides '0'. For '123' it would be provide the numbers 1, 2 and 3 in three loops and so on.
The question would be why use that second loop at all if you want the whole number values of the cell remove that loop and use the rest of the code.

Comment: Also not sure how you print out the value of 'aoi' before its assigned in the next line, but not important if the above is what you want.